# Apache 500 server error- logs showing nothing

Tags: php, apache

Just after some help with a new installation of PHP.

I've setup a new Centos 6.2 server with apache PHP and am having trouble getting errors to show.
I've copied all the website application files from a different as well as the folder structure and everything in /etc/httpd/.

When I access my site, I get a 500 error, or a blank page. The logs are showing nothing at all, apart form logging the 500 error:

```
[24/Feb/2012:17:33:25 +1100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.1" 405 229 7176
```

My htaccess looks like this:
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

```
php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
php_flag  file_uploads                    on
php_value error_reporting                 6143
php_value max_input_time                  60
php_value post_max_size                   8M
php_value upload_max_filesize             2M
~
```

So errors are turned on...

```
Start of PHP file has:
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

and php.ini has error_reporting set to E_ALL.

... yet I am getting errors on the screen for some things (such as not closing a string), but my issues are a bit bigger than i think and i have no idea where to start debugging!

So i guess my question is- how do I start debugging a 500 server error?

Comment: You log entry shows a `200` status code.

Comment: sometimes .htaccess files might interfeer with other .htaccess files in subfolders

Comment: I know this is old and closed, but I had a similar issue. Turns out, I had short tags in my code "<?". So I didn't have "<?php", This was causing the page to crash with no discernible error output.

Comment: **Why was this closed?** Only one of the five users who closed this question, @hjpotter92, has **any php experience** in their tags. It's as if they read the title alone and assumed it was an Apache question. It's not. It's about finding error messages in PHP, a programming language.

Answer (score 15):

When error messages are maddeningly missing from the screen and from the Apache error_log files and anywhere else, I've had good luck getting them to appear by adding a different PHP file, using it only for development:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 include("productioncode.php");
?>
```

This way, even if productioncode.php has compile-time errors the above code runs, and the messages get displayed, unlike merely putting the first two lines at the top of productioncode.php.

@Jaspreet Chahal and @Saiyam Patel - I just recovered from a lovely evening of error 500's in the access_log, e.g.

```
77.22.98.222 - - [26/Feb/2012:22:38:41 -0500] "GET /buggycode.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - west-real-estate.com "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.0; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" "PHPSESSID=hcd04vv9e1a316cr9miauf3bl5" - 0
```

and no PHP error messages in any httpd log file from (foolishly) coding { 'foo' => 'bar' } instead of array( 'foo' => 'bar' ).  Using the above technique revealed the detailed error message, including the all-important line number.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, OP is talking about the case where errors are turned on and still nothing is printed or logged. This won't solve that.

Comment: Hmm, it may not solve the OP's case, but it will solve some problems that fit the subject of TFA "Apache 500 server error- logs showing nothing".  (Including when you further restrict to cases where errors are "turned on" in the source file.)  So I believe the trick could be useful to others searching.

Comment: BobStein, your wisdom just saved me a lot of trouble! I can finally see what's wrong with my code, I was getting error 500 and there was nothing in logs, but with your solution I'm finally able to track this frigin bug!

@edit
I love you. Took me 3 minutes to eliminate my bug after using your solution to display the exact error server was throwing.

Answer (score 1):

Apache 500 server error 
This is not a PHP error this is Server error (Server Unable to handle your request)
OR may be problem with .htaccess file probably redirection

cheers

Comment: Yes Dude , its .htaccess issue with mine.. Thanks for your help. you saved my day.. Regards Man. Cheers..

Comment: Apache can very well serve up a 500 error in the event of a PHP fatal error.

Comment: As Mike said, an error 500 means " "Sorry, something is generally wrong with the resource you try to access. We can't say what it is, but it surely is on our side." Most times it is really a DB problem, or sessions... kinda application-level configuration.

Comment: Ok, but how to enable logging or even show 500 Apache errors? Where I can find logs for them because Apache log is empty. How I can find a reason of this 500 if all logs are empty even if log_levels are warn or debug or error? I tried so many solutions from StackOverflow and I can't still figure it out why some of my app pages are displaying 500 errors :(

Answer (score 1):

just try to check from your config file where are the logs stored. What you showed is an access log not error log I guess. so just check where is error log getting stored. Cheers! As you said its centos Check this directory `/var/logs/httpd` and check for `error_log` file. if its a custom log then search for that file.

btw 500 is a server error so for me I think it has to do something with your configuration or db connection setup.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes that directory has error log but has nothing in it at all! I don't think it's htaccess as I know I havnt installed an odbc library and through echoing, this is where it stops working.. But I know this won't be the only issue so need to see the errors. Is there a logging level in apache that needs to be amped up to show these errors?